# Writing MySQL query with several table joins or multiple select

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-select-query

I am trying to write a MySQL query that gives me results of Organisation Name, its Post Code, any Events that belong to the Organisation and the Post Code of that Event. I've tried all sorts of of join, join and select combinations to no avail. Is this something that is possible ? (I could have a separate table for Org Address and Event Address but it seems like it should be possible to use just one table)

My table structures:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE cc_organisations;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type        | enum('C','O')    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(150)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE cc_events;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| org_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(150)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_date  | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_date    | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_time  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_time    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE cc_addresses;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| org_id       | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| event_id     | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_code    | varchar(7)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address_1    | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address_2    | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| town         | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| county       | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone        | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| website_uri  | varchar(150)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| facebook_uri | varchar(250)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| twitter_uri  | varchar(250)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you assign both org_id and event_id at the same time or are they mutually exclusive in cc_addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select o.Name, oAddress.PostCode, e.Name, eAddress.PostCode 
from cc_organisations o
inner join cc_addresses oAddress on oAddress.org_id = o.id
left outer join cc_events e on e.org_id=o.id
inner join cc_addresses eAddress on eAddress.event_id = e.id
```

Comment: Might need to check for isnull(oAddress.event_id) on the first join depending on whether both event_id and org_id can be set at the same time in cc_addresses.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I didn't even know about outer joins, so I'll go away and read up on those as that seems to be the magic ingredient!

Comment: As a learning point, what is the difference between your SQL and this: SELECT o.name, o_address.post_code, e.name, e_address.post_code
FROM cc_organisations AS o
LEFT JOIN cc_addresses AS o_address LEFT OUTER JOIN cc_events AS e LEFT JOIN cc_addresses AS e_address
ON o_address.org_id = o.id AND e.org_id = o.id AND e_address.org_id = e.id
WHERE o.user_id = 1;

Comment: I believe you don't need the LEFT join in this example - sorry! Try changing the left outer join to an inner join. The join should repeat the records in organisation for the records in events. You use a left join to include records that have a NULL id in the right have table. Wiki should help you on inner/left/right/outer joins

Comment: Your SQL is very hard to read as all the where are at the last ON clauses. I wouldn't recommend doing it like that. They're probably both valid sql but it's good practise to put your filters for the table join in that ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT cco.name as OrgName, cca.post_code as OrgPostCode, cce.id,
        cce.org_id, cce.name, cce.start_date, cce.end_date, cce.start_time,
        cce.end_time, cce.description
 FROM   cc_events cce, cc_addresses cca, cc_organisations cco
 WHERE  cca.event_id = cce.id AND cco.id=cce.org_id 
 ORDER BY cce.start_date
 LIMIT 50;
```

You can change your sort and limit, I just added those in because I don't know how big your DB is... You may even be able to get away with:

```
SELECT cco.name as OrgName, cca.post_code as OrgPostCode, cce.*
FROM cc_events cce, cc_addresses cca, cc_organisations cco
WHERE  cca.event_id = cce.id AND cco.id=cce.org_id
ORDER BY cce.start_date LIMIT 50;
```

But im not 100% sure if the 2nd query will bum out or not.

Your `address` table has the post codes in it; but it also has an organization id and event id foreign keys. We only need to check the `event_id` from the `address` table because any event will belong to an organization.

- Address's Event matched Event ID
- Event's Organization matched Organization ID

Comment: With an implicit inner join you won't see organizations with no events.  Also, this query won't return the addresses tied specifically to an organization but not an event.  (have to use cc_addresses.org_id for that)